# How do I catch an exception in intern JS?

Tags: javascript, intern, leadfoot

I have the following snippet

```
,clickStaleElement: function(remote, id) {
  return remote
    .findById(id)
      .execute(function(id){
        //force org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException
        $(document.getElementById(id)).addClass('hidden');
      },[id])
      .click()
      .catch(function(){
        return this.parent
          .findById(id)
            .execute(function(id){
              //bring back the element
              $(document.getElementById(id)).removeClass('hidden');
            },[id])
            .click()
          .end()
        ;
      })
    .end()
  ;
}
```

which is supposed to handle `StaleElementReferenceException`, or any other for that matter, and try to find the element again and click on it. The element is added and removed to/from the dom on a fixed interval and therefore sometimes i get this exception in my test run and therefore a failed run. I want to handle this exception and prevent the run from failing as is not really failing due to a bug (or is it?).

So the question is **How do I handle an exception on the `.click()` method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your callback, try using `remote` instead of `this.parent`. `this.parent` uses the same context element as the parent chain. This means that if you ended up in the catch because you tried to click a stale element, calling `this.parent.findById(id)` in the `catch` will be performing a search rooted on that stale element.

Comment: yep. that was it.

Comment: how do I write loop checking until some limit or until clicked? The fixed interval makes this worthless as exception might happen on the inner click?

Comment: I mean that in the `.catch`, `.click()` might trigger another StaleElementException because the element is added and removed on a fixed interval, so just capturing once doesn't suffice. You need code which retries the `.click` method if an exception happens until success or until a limit is reached... Anyway I figured it out myself already. Might open a Q/A myself.